# How to implement a derivative of a unitary gate in a quantum circuit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11184)<sup>1</sup>, which says in Eqn(15) that the derivative of a unitary gate with respect to the parameter $\mu$ can be decomposed into linear combinations of unitary gates.
However, I didn't understand how to determine the coefficient, $\alpha$ in there.
I want to implement a derivative operation in a quantum circuit.  Could anyone help with the proof of that statement in Eq(15)?

---

<sup>1</sup>Reference: M. Schuld, V. Bergholm, C. Gogolin, J. Izaac, and N. Killoran, "Evaluating analytic gradients on quantum hardware", [*Phys. Rev. A* **99**, 032331 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.032331), [arXiv:1811.11184](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11184).

Comment: You might want to check out [SE.QuantumComputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Nat This question is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: There is no point in implementing the derivative of a unitary, since it is not unitary (but rather a product of a hermitian and a unitary): gates in quantum circuits must be unitary.  You must mean sth. else.  -- BTW, please link to the abstract!